# Svg is loaded but not displayed by browsers

Tags: nginx, svg

I set up a nextcloud 10 with docker and an nginx in front. Everything is loaded exclude svg grafics. There are reachabel but they are not diplayed. If load the svg grafic in an seperate window I only see the svg code. There is an pre tag around the svg code. If I remove the tag, the svg icon will be rendered correct. I do not why the browsers do not render the icons on page. Because nginx shows me, that they are loaded.

Mabye I miss something in nginx, but what is the important part of the puzzle? All other grafik are loaded and displayed correct. the svg grafic be loaded as an source of an image tag.

Comment: Check that your SVG files are being served with the correct `Content-type`. It should be `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: thank you, svg type was not in the mimetype file, after adding it works fine.